# How to Add Months to date then convert to different format in Spark.SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, date-formatting

I am trying to run the below command in spark.sql  but keep getting an error.

```
SELECT to_date(ADD_MONTHS(current_date()::date, 5),'YYYYMM') AS RESULT;
```

All I am trying to do is add 5 months to the current date and then convert the format to 'YYYYMM' instead of the deafAult (YYYY-MM-DD).

I also tried this but to no avail:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(ADD_MONTHS(CAST(current_date() AS DATE),5),'YYYYMM') AS DATE_1;
```

I have tried many things but to know avail. Anyone know how to resolve this?

I just want the output to be in this format:

```
'202308' 0R '20238'
```

Comment: Which spark version are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're formatting a date, you can use `to_char`

```
select to_char(add_months(current_date(), 5),'yyyymm');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `DATE_FORMAT` - format `'yyyyMM'` :

```
select DATE_FORMAT(ADD_MONTHS(current_date(),5),'yyyyMM') AS DATE_1;
```